# Find Fourier Series of the function $f(x)= \sin x \cos(2x) $

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Find Fourier Series of the function $f(x)= \sin x \cos(2x) $ in the range
$ -\pi \leq x \leq \pi $

any help much appreciated

I need find out

$a_0$ and $a_1$ and $b_1$

I can find $a_0$ which is simply integrating something with respect to the limits I can get as far as

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \ \frac12 (\sin (3x)-\sin(x)) dx$$

How would I integrate the above expression ?

secondly how would I calculate $a_1$ and $b_1$
but despite knowing the [general formula](http://www.enm.bris.ac.uk/admin/courses/EMa2/Lecture%20Notes%2009-10/FourierSummary.pdf)  to find the fourier series Im having trouble applying them to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use integration to find $a_0$, $a_1$, and $b_1$, you can use

$a_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin x\cos{2x}dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{2}(\sin{3x}-\sin x) dx=0$ since the integrand is an odd function.

$a_1=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin x\cos{2x}\cos x dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\sin x\cos x)\cos{2x}dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{2}\sin{2x}\cos{2x}dx=$
$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{4}\sin{4x}dx=0$ for the same reason.

$b_1=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin x\cos{2x}\sin xdx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^{2} x\cos{2x}dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos{2x})\cos{2x}dx$

Comment: How do you know $a_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin x\cos{2x}dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{2}(\sin{3x}-\sin x) dx=0$ is equal to 0 ?


and other contributors have suggested the answer is 
$$ \frac12 (\sin (3x)-\sin(x)) dx$$  whilst your answer for b1 is different. This confuses me

Comment: I am using the fact that if $f(x)$ is an odd function, so $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x$, then $\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx=0$. What other responders are saying is that the identity $\sin x\cos 2x=\frac{1}{2}(\sin 3x-\sin x)$ already gives the Fourier series you want (without any integration).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\sin x \cos 2x = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sin 3x - \sin x \right).$$

Comment: Is this an example of a unique solution ? and its not possible to integrate the answer further

Comment: You don't need to integrate anything. It is the Fourier series:
$$b_1 = -\frac12, \quad b_3 = \frac12$$
and all other coefficients $=0$.

Comment: but surely to find a0(http://www.enm.bris.ac.uk/admin/courses/EMa2/Lecture%20Notes%2009-10/FourierSummary.pdf) , I need to integrate once I have gotten the function in sin form ?

Comment: For other functions you will need to use those formulas. You can use them in this case too, but in such special cases it is more convenient to find the Fourier series directly.

Comment: so the final answer would just be $$\frac{1}{2} \left( \sin 3x - \sin x \right).$$ is that the answer to a0 ? or the final answer to fourier series

Comment: It is the final answer.

Comment: thanks, if I see another question like this, how do I know in which case I use those formulas and in which case its a special case and I just need to put the expression in either cos or sin form .

Comment: If you can rewrite your function as a sum of sines and cosines, then that is your Fourier series and you're done. In general, though, you have to use the integration formulas to find the coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of integrating, it is easier to just use the trigonometric product formula
$$ \sin(a) \cos(b) = \frac{\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b)}{2} $$
to rewrite the function into a form that it is own Fourier expansion.

Comment: but my textbook says I have to use the method that involves finding a0,an,bn and to find them I have to integrate

Comment: @Emm91: No, integration is not the only way to find the Fourier coefficients. After rewriting with the product formula you can read them directly off the resulting formula.